# Polymer iron-form post method not working $_POST variable empty

Tags: php, forms, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

when i use post method `iron-form` does not work but get method works.
Here is code:

test.php:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady",function() {
        document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener('iron-form-submit',function(e){
            });
        document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener('iron-form-response',function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });
        document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener('iron-form-error',function(e,s,d){
            console.log(e);
            alert('iron form error!');
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/user/put">
        <input name="address" required>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
</body>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

when i submit form screenshot of headers innetwork tab:
[image: Screenshot of headers in network tab when form submit]

response tab:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is because using iron-form POST datas are sent in JSON format, look at the browser developper tools Params tab to see what is sent !

var_dump($_POST) in php script return an empty string if not decoded.

Try file_get_contents with php://input to access I/O stream and json_decode on server side, like this:

Server side php script:

```
<?php
$datas = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($datas, true);

$return = '<ul>';
foreach($_POST as $index=>$val) {
    $return .= '<li>'.$index.'/'.$val.'</li>';
}
$return .= '</ul>';

echo '{"my_return": "'.$return.'"}';
```

And the Polymer component:

```
<dom-module id="my-form">
    <template>
        <div class="horizontal center-center layout">
            <div>
                <div class="horizontal-section">
                    <form is="iron-form" id="formGet" method="post" action="add.php">
                        <paper-input name="name" label="Name" value="John Doe" required></paper-input>
                        <paper-input name="age" label="Age" value="97" required></paper-input>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <paper-button raised onclick="clickHandler(event)">Submit</paper-button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>

        function clickHandler(event) {
            Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
        }

        Polymer({
            is: 'my-form',
            listeners: {
                'iron-form-response': 'formResponse',
                'iron-form-submit': 'formSubmit',
                'iron-form-error': 'formError'
            },
            formError: function(e) {
                alert(e.detail.error);
        },
        formSubmit: function(e) {
            //alert(document.getElementById("formGet").serialize().name);
            //alert(document.getElementById("formGet").serialize().age);
        },
        formResponse: function(e) {
             document.getElementById('contentECLP').innerHTML = e.detail.my_return;
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hmm thats work but why polymer team don't mention about it in any documents?

Comment: one more thing now how i can upload file with iron-form according to your solution only file path is passed in $_POST variable and $_FILES variable is empty?

Answer (score 0):

According to your network log `iron-form` *is* working correctly, the problem must be on the PHP side.

Offhand it looks like you're submitting to `/user/put` but your `var_dump` is in an `index.php`, make sure your file paths are correct.

Comment: all request all redirecting to index.php. It runs and `var_dump($_POST);` its output also show in response which is empty i attached it in image